# Capybara wait until button is enabled?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

Surprised I actually haven't come across this, but I have a simple button that is disabled until a dropdown is selected. Sometimes the page isn't fast enough to "enable" the button to be clicked on after the previous dropdown is selected causing it to fail.

I could throw in a "sleep" of a second or two and fix this, but that seems like a lazy/poor way to do this.

Is there a way in capybara (or purely selenium) that I can make it wait until the button is actually enabled? I'd like to throw this is the page model method for this button (as im trying to avoid API specific methods/selenium/etc... in the actual test specs (Although I can if I need to).

FWIW this is specifically for Ruby's capybara framework but pure selenium is fine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the button you're referring to is actually a button (<button> element, or <input> element with type submit, reset, image, or button) then Capybaras :button selector will (by default) wait for it to be non-disabled.

```
click_button('Something')
```

or

```
find_button('button_id').click
```

or

```
find(:button, 'button_value').click
```

If any of the finder or action methods aren't waiting long enough for a specific element you can always increase the maximum wait time for a specific finder/action by passing a :wait option

```
find(:button, 'Something', wait: 10).click
```

If you're not using selector types (if not, why not) and instead are just using raw CSS to locate the element then  you can use the `:enabled` pseudo class along with your existing CSS and something like

```
find('#my_button:enabled', wait: 10).click
```

If the element you're calling a button isn't actually a button but some other type of element (<a> etc) styled to look like a button, then you'll need to explain exactly how you're disabling the "button".

Comment: Im using `click_button` as it is actually a button with a `disabled` tag, but it seems to fail regardless. But this could just be a wait time problem as since it's a dropdown animation maybe it's just not long enough.

Can I do something like `click_button('button', wait: 10)` ? Or do I specifically need to use find.

Also what exactly do you mean by "selector" types. Im selecting based off the label text.

Comment: Yes, you can pass `wait` like that to `click_button`. As for selector types, 
 `click_button('x'')` is implemented as `find(:button, 'x').click` where `:button` is the selector type. Capybara provides a number of selector types - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L52 - that find specific types of elements with relevant filters - and you can add your own custom selector types too - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#xpath-css-and-selectors.

Comment: Since you mention animation - it's also possible the button is enabled but being moved on the page.  That can also make clicking unreliable since the click doesn't always happen in the right place. To solve that you would need to find something on the page that indicates the animation has completed, change the page to only enable the button once the animation has completed, or disable animation while testing.  The best way to disable animation depends on everything being used for the animation, but setting `Capybara.disable_animation = true` in your config can do it in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can do something like this:

```
def wait_until_clickable(driver, xpath, timeout = 1):
    while timeout > 0:
        try:
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
            element.click()
            return element

        except:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            timeout = timeout - 0.1

    return False
```

Comment: Unfortunately im purely running on ruby in this case :/

Comment: I added the Ruby tag to the question